# Existe algun log de los querys ejecutados en Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

vengo usando postgresql 9.3, quisiera saber si existe algún log de los querys ejecutados, y si hay forma de activar para que se genere uno

Comment: Revisa en la ruta: `Usuario/PostgreSQL/data/logs/pg93` si no encuentras ahí el tipo de logs que buscas, significa que tienes que activarlos, modificando el archivo `postgresql.conf` que se encuentra en la ruta: `Usuario/PostgreSQL/data/pg93`  es un archivo con varias secciones, debes buscar la que se titula `ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING` y configurar allí el tipo de logs que quieras escribir/reportar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe verificar en el archivo de configuración que esten activos los logs

logging_collector = on

log_directory = 'pg_log'

log_statement = 'all'

La última linea imprime en el log todas las consultas ejecutadas.

Un ejemplo de la configuación con docker esta en:

https://github.com/tutmosisII/SOQuestions/tree/master/SOPostgres/Q202552